# how to get "title" attribute of all visible <li> elements in specefic <ul> using jquery, collect theme in an array and display them using alert();

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get "title" attributes of all visible `<li>` elements in specefic `<ul>`, collect theme in an array and display them using `alert()` function with jQuery?

for example I have :

```
<ul class="ulCats">
     <li title="1"></li>
     <li title="2" style="display: none;"></li>
     <li title="3"></li>
     <li title="4" style="display: none;"></li>
     <li title="5" style="display: none;"></li>
</ul>
```

and what i'm looking for is :

```
VisibleLiTitles = "2-4-5"
```

Comment: maybe you want 1-3 as result?

Comment: What you are looking for is the opposite of what you are asking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one possible way:

```
var VisibleLiTitles = $('.ulCats li:visible').map(function() {
    return this.title;
}).get().join('-');

alert(VisibleLiTitles);
```

For *invisible* elements use [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector instead.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/m6cfB/

Answer (score 2):

Select that `li` by,

```
var visibleValues = "";

$('.ulCats li:visible').each(function(){
     visibleValues += this.title + "-";
});

visibleValues = visibleValues.substr(0, visibleValues.length - 1);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m6cfB/1/)

---

[**`Performance comparison`**](http://jsperf.com/mine-vision) with the VisioN's answer.

Comment: Where are the hyphens between them?

Comment: @Barmar Please wait, i have been thinking a diff logic. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy It is always good to think ***before*** posting an answer.

Comment: Unless your logic is better than VisioN's, don't bother.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah.. But i just satisfied that i had posted a different soln. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try following:--

```
var visibleLis = [];

$('ul.ulCats li:visible').each(function(){
     visibleLis.push($(this).attr('title'));
})


alert(visibleLis.join('-'));
```

Comment: `visibleLis.get()` this part is incorrect if applied to *your* solution.